# ASP NET Web Forms can not register User Control (ascx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, ascx

I have a user control with the following directive

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SelectorControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="SelectorControl" %>
```

and then I can register this control in any .aspx and use, like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="FolderDistribution.aspx.cs"
   Inherits="SearchFolder.FolderDistribution" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="UC" TagName="TemplateSelection" Src="~/Controls/SelectorControl.ascx" %>

<div>
   <UC:TemplateSelection ID="templates" runat="server" />
</div>
```

But, I need to set **CodeFile** in my UserControl (ascx) instead of **CodeBehind**.  In control's directive I changed
`CodeBehind="SelectorControl.ascx.cs"` to `CodeFile="SelectorControl.ascx.cs"`

And in this case I get the following runtime error

```
The base class includes the field 'templates', but its type (TemplateSelection) is not >compatible with the type of control (ASP.controls__templateselection_ascx).
```

---

Comment: sorry, when you say change the "codefile" are you talking about the visual part? Exactly what do you change?

Comment: @Julián
In control's directive I changed 
`CodeBehind="SelectorControl.ascx.cs"` to `CodeFile="SelectorControl.ascx.cs"`